# Ruby - Como acertar o LOAD_PATH em tempo de desenvolvimento?

Tags: ruby, projeto-de-software, organização-de-projeto

Em primeiro lugar: Eu sou um novato em Ruby.

Eu tenho um projeto em Ruby que obedece ao padrão de projeto da grande maioria dos projetos. Portanto, o executável principal fica em bin/.

```
bin/exec
lib/ 
    |
     -- library.rb
     -- library/
```

O problema é que o executável principal depende do library.rb para rodar corretamente, e o library.rb depende de todo o resto dentro do diretório library.

Se eu empacotar o projeto numa gem e instalar essa gem, o executável principal roda porque o Rubygems vai cuidar de tudo, mas isso tem a desvantagem de que o executável principal não enxerga as mudanças dentro do diretório lib.

Isso sempre me leva a escrever código como esse:

```
$: << File.expand_path('../lib')
```

E em library.rb:

```
$: << File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

Isso resolve o problema, mas distribuir o software com esse código é distribuir software com "debug code". E no pior dos casos isso pode causar um bug, caso algum azarado rode o executável principal num diretório onde coincidentemente também há um diretório chamado "lib" e por uma coincidência maior ainda, haja um arquivo chamado library.rb dentro do diretório.

Como deixar o LOAD_PATH correto em tempo de desenvolvimento sem necessidade de poluir o código?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que suas preocupações com esse código não deveriam existir. Diferente do que você afirma, esse é o procedimento padrão pra todas as aplicações com arquivos executáveis em Ruby: o executável fica em `bin/` e este adiciona o `../lib` no load path.